# Inflation cosmology: slow-roll inflation versus tunneling between two vacua

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, early-universe

In slow-roll inflation models, the early inflation of the universe is driven by the flat non-zero part of the inflaton potential, and it ends as the ball rolls down the cliff and the potential energy released leads then to the formation of matter.

[image]

However, as I have heard such slow-roll models are no longer deemed realistic today in inflationary cosmology, instead other models where the end of the inflation is explained by quantum tunneling of the universe from a state with higher vacuum energy density to another state with lower vacuum energy density are considered for example.

[image]

Why (from a physical point of view) are slow-roll inflation models no longer considered to be realistic, what are their disadvantages? What can models that explain (the end of) the early inflation by a tunneling transition between to vacua explain or describe, that slow roll models can not do?

Comment: Do you have references that can be included in this question?

Comment: @UV-D I certainly could find some references ..., I first learned about these things in Lenny Susskind's online cosmology course.

Comment: @TildalWave I have cleaned up the comments about the on-topicness of this post. The discussion about where cosmology and theoretical astrophysics, as well as astrophysics in general, fall in our scope has moved to [Meta](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-much-is-astrophysics-cosmology-and-theoretical-astrophysics-on-topic).

Comment: @Dilaton that'd be a good and helpful addition to this excellent question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I...think you've got it backwards? Slow-roll inflation is alive and well, unlike models which involve tunneling between two vacua. The model of inflation first proposed by Alan Guth back in 1980 was a tunneling model. But it had a serious problem: it didn't *reheat*. Tunneling from a false vacuum to a true one (or a lower-energy false one) wouldn't release any radiation. And we need that radiation, because we *are* that radiation, cooled down and condensed after nearly 14 billion years of expansion. The solution was slow-roll inflation: as you mentioned in your question, rolling down the potential well releases a great deal of energy, which in turn leads to the wide variety of matter and radiation in the universe today. Slow-roll inflation also does a nice job of predicting the tiny density fluctuations in the early universe that seeded the formation of all the structures in the universe. Wikipedia has [more on all of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_%28cosmology%29#Early_inflationary_models).

A small disclaimer: there's a lot of inflationary models out there in the literature (there's a hilarious partial list in footnote 3 of [this excellent paper by Yadav and Wandelt](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0275)), and for all I know, one or more of them involve vacuum decay. But the dominant paradigm for inflation today is definitely slow-roll.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer, these explanations are indeed the other way round from what I have heared or read ... What I do not yet see right now is why the "latent energy" released by some kind of a vacuum transition (the difference between the two values for the cosmological constant constants) can not be turned into radiation (= photons?) apart from other stuff ... Will have to look deeper at the reheating problem a bit.